# Gradle how to replace the obsolete 'variantOutput.getPackageLibrary()' with 'variant.getPackageLibraryProvider()'?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have an Android library project with several flavours. I upload the aar files of these different flavours to a private repository using the `'maven-publish'` plugin. I've been using the `variant.outputs[0].outputFile`as the value for the `publishing.publications.artifact` parameter.

```
publishing.publications.create variant.flavorName, MavenPublication, {
            groupId "$libraryGroupId.$variant.flavorName"
            artifactId libraryArtifactId
            version libraryVersion
            artifact variant.outputs[0].outputFile           
        }
```

It's been working great, but I've recently updated the library's gradle plugin to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2` and get the following warning:

> WARNING: API 'variantOutput.getPackageLibrary()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getPackageLibraryProvider()'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2019.
>   For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
>   To determine what is calling variantOutput.getPackageLibrary(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace.

It's not an issue per se, as it still works, but I don't like this warning and as I've been cleaning things up in my `build.gradle`, I thought I'd try to fix it.

I've tried a lot of different combinations, raking the internet to try to find info on how to obtain the aar from the package library provider. There is close to nothing available on the subject (which is really frustrating) but I did find [this post](https://blog.csdn.net/angcyo/article/details/78357512) which led me to try with:

`variant.getPackageLibraryProvider().get()`

This provides a [`com.android.build.gradle.tasks.BundleAar`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio-master-dev/build-system/gradle-core/src/main/java/com/android/build/gradle/tasks/BundleAar.kt) which seems to be working when set as the artifact of the publication (`artifact variant.getPackageLibraryProvider().get()`) and fixes the warning.

Is this the right way to fix this warning or will it backfire on me for some reason? Does anyone know where I could get more info about this?

Comment: I do this:     libraryVariants.all { variant ->

        variant.outputs.all { output ->

            def outputFile = output.outputFile ... }} and I am getting the same warning.

Comment: @ScubaInstructor it's just a slightly different way of doing the same thing and will still use the "obsolete" API, so it won't solve the issue. I did try it out among other combinations, half hoping it would work, but the reality is that the api is truly at the root of the warning ;) .

Comment: I just wanted to say that I get the same warning that you get with my approach. I am looking for a solution as well.

Comment: @Dude did you find a solution?

Comment: @Pierre I've been using variant.getPackageLibraryProvider().get() for some time now and it works fine. It hasn't backfired for the moment.

Comment: Thank you, I have implemented it and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Gradle](https://github.com/gradle/gradle.git) and [Android Gradle Plugin](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/refs/heads/master/) sources as reference, I came up with the following and the warning is gone:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
            if (variant.buildType.name == "release") {
                aar(MavenPublication) {
                    artifact(variant.packageLibraryProvider.get().archivePath)
                    groupId = '<your group id>'
                    artifactId = "$project.name"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```